# Hibernate cascade setting for many2many relationship

Tags: hibernate

```
public class Job {
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "t_job_t_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> operator = new ArrayList<User>();

}

public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    //have no reference to Job
}
```

Now I can not delete `User` object since I will get the exception:

`Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ....`

Seems that this is caused by the association between the two entity.

I wonder how to fix that?

---

Why I avoid to add the reference in `User` is that:

1 There is no need to know the jobs from the perspective of user logically.

2 Avoid the cascade query when query operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference in the User class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="operator")
private List<Job> job;
```

Now you can either add `cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE` to the `@ManyToMany` annotation (this can cause more problems if other users are referencing the job), or you have to take care to delete the user references from the affected jobs before deleting the user:

```
public void delete(User user) {
    for (Job job : user.getJobs()) {
        job.getOperator().remove(user);
    }
    user.getJobs().clear();
    entityManager.remove(user);
}
```